# Code Review with Git inside Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

We're using TFS 2015 with the built-in Git integration. So far, I've managed to create pull-requests and perform code review via the web interface, but we would prefer to have a solution integrated into the IDE.

I have looked at [Review Assistant](http://www.devart.com/review-assistant/) and I'm not sure whether it can connect to our existing TFS server. (It seems to require its own custom review server?)

---

**EDIT:** The main functionality we desire is being able to look at past history of a particular method to see if it has been code reviewed, what comments were made previously, and what changes have been made since then. Also being able to determine code-coverage would be nice.

Can this be done by the existing web interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 has a "pull request" hub in Team Explorer that will give you limited access to pull requests. However, pull requests are first and foremost web-based in TFS, and I don't expect that will change.

You can use branch policies in conjunction with pull requests to enforce builds (which can generate code coverage metrics) and required code review. Then there's no question: If it's been merged, it's been reviewed.